# How don't call didDeactivate and didActivate in CallKit

Tags: swift, avaudiosession, callkit

I have a problem with the double call on `CallKit`. When I accept a new call I lose the `sound/audio`. I think the problem comes when `didDeactivate` and `didActivate` are called because when I manually disable and reactivate `AVAudioSession` I also lose the `sound/audio`. I wanted to know if it was possible to disable `didDeactivate` and `didActivate`...

Thank you.

```
func provider(_ provider: CXProvider, didActivate audioSession: AVAudioSession) {
    print("Received \(#function)")
    print("ACTIVATE")
    activateAudioSession()
}


func provider(_ provider: CXProvider, didDeactivate audioSession: AVAudioSession) {
    print("Received \(#function)")
    print("DEACTIVATE")
    deactivateAudioSession()
}


- (void) activateAudioSession {

    AVAudioSession *audioSession = [AVAudioSession sharedInstance];
    NSError *setError = nil;

    [audioPlayer play];

    [audioSession setActive: NO error: nil];
    if (![[audioSession category] isEqualToString:AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayAndRecord])
        [audioSession setCategory:AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayAndRecord withOptions:AVAudioSessionCategoryOptionDefaultToSpeaker|AVAudioSessionCategoryOptionAllowBluetooth error:&setError];
    if (![[audioSession mode] isEqualToString:AVAudioSessionModeVoiceChat])
        if ([AVAudioSession instancesRespondToSelector: @selector (setMode:error:)]) {
            [audioSession setMode:AVAudioSessionModeVoiceChat error:&setError];
        }

    [audioSession setActive: YES withOptions:AVAudioSessionCategoryOptionDefaultToSpeaker|AVAudioSessionCategoryOptionAllowBluetooth error: nil];

}


- (void) deactivateAudioSession {
    AVAudioSession *audioSession = [AVAudioSession sharedInstance];
    [audioPlayer stop];
    [audioSession setActive: NO error: nil];
}
```

Comment: Oh, yes, it's hello, by the way.

Comment: The `didActivate` and `didDeactivate` functions, as the name suggests, are called after the audio session has been activated and deactivated respectively; why are you trying to re-activate/deactivate the audio session inside those functions?

Comment: @Marco yes I removed them but I looked in my code and I don't see where my sound is turned off (and so which triggers "didDeactivate"). It is disabled when I put it in "Put on hold and answer"